# Publish image on Facebook with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, social-networking

I'm trying to publish an image on Facebook using PHP SDK but I can't get the session connection. I'm using PHP 5.5.20 and the latest official SDK provided by Facebook. For now I've done only a test code for see how use this SDK but it always requests the log-in without set the session token, or it returns the error: "request error: couldn't connect to host". Where I wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Frameworks/Facebook/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$api_key = '[APP_KEY]';
$api_secret = '[SECRET_KEY]';
$redirect_login_url = 'http://sketchy.ga/test.php';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($api_key, $api_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_login_url);
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
    try {
        if ( !$session->validate() ) $session = null;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $session = null;
        echo 'No session: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}  elseif ( empty( $session ) ) {
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
        echo 'Facebook (session) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        echo 'Other (session) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
    $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
    try {
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 
            'POST', 
            '/me/feed', 
            array(
                'message' => 'Hello world!!'
            )
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
        $msgid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');
    } catch ( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
        echo 'Facebook (post) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    if ( isset ( $msgid ) ) {
        $parts = explode('_', $msgid);
        try {
            $request2 = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                '/'.$parts[1]
            );
            $response2 = $request2->execute();
            $graphObject2 = $response2->getGraphObject();
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject2, 1 ) . '</pre>';
        } catch ( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
            echo 'Facebook (get) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'No session, please <a href="'. $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'publish_actions' ) ).'">login</a>.';
}
?>
```

Comment: That sounds like a connectivity problem between your server and Facebook’s servers.

Comment: @CBroe I've tried with different SDK for different social networks without success, so I've contacted the hosting's assistance for informations and they say me that the connections to social networks are been disabled, there is a way for connect to the socials with this block using a proxy in cURL?

Comment: If they block outgoing requests to other servers, then you likely won’t have success with any approach to use the FB (or other social network) APIs server-side. What you could try then is doing stuff client-side, f.e. by using the FB JS SDK.